Pinescript trying to draw lines for previous daily ohlc
I try to draw previous daily ( for now once I get it it will be weekly % monthly as well) ohlc starting from beginning of daily bar and extended to the right
the problem I get when I use array.set(pdtime,x, request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', time[x])) is I can't use this in a loop, can't use a loop with request.security... I need another way to get the ohlc into an array, and to be able to draw lines using the array.get
thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Stackoverflow is not a coding service. To get an answer, you must share your code. What you tried, or reproduce the unexpected behavior.
